# How to assign Authorization Token in Oracle SOA Suite

Tags: soa, jdeveloper, oracle-ebs, oracle-soa

I am trying to call REST API of Azure using Oracle SOA Suite. I am unable to access as it is showing below error :

MissingToken: The authorization header was not found

I need to assign the SAS token everytime the webservice call using Authorization header. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any OWSM policy?you need to attach these owsm policies oracle/oauth2_config_client_policy,oracle/http_oauth2_token_client_policy to the partner link in your composite.

Comment: Do you have any document , how to create and assign these policies?